# How can I solve error "Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null "

Tags: javascript, html

```
<html>
<body>
<p>maximum number:<input type="text" id="number"></p>
<p>how many questions?<input type="text" id="questions"></p>
<button onclick="button()"> ok </button>
<div id = 'div'> </div>
<div id = 'div2'> </div>

  <script>
    var rand1, rand2, text1, text2
    function button(){
      text1 = document.getElementById("number").value;
      // text2 = document.getElementById('questions').value;
      rand1 = Math.floor(Math.random() * text1);
      rand2 = Math.floor(Math.random() * text1);
      var html = "<input type='number' id='id'> <button onclick=' check() '> check </button> <button onclick=' again() '> again </button>" + Number(rand2) + '+' + Number(rand1);
      document.getElementById('div').innerHTML = html;
      var text1 = document.getElementById('number').value;
      document.write(html);
    }
    var rand3, rand4
    function again(){
      rand3 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10);
      rand4 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10);
      var html1 = Number(rand3) + '+' + Number(rand4);
      document.getElementById('div2').innerHTML = html1;
    }
    function check(){
      var answer = rand1 + rand2;
      var text11 = document.getElementById('id').value;
      if(answer == text11) {
        document.write('<br>' + 'correct!');
      } else {
        document.write('<br>' + 'incorrect!');
      }
    }
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

This JS / HTML code is supposed to give me an equation like 1 + 1 and then if I click on again I get another one. But this gives me the error Untitled.html:20 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null. I have been researching this for half an hour and it says that I need to put the divs in front of the script. But I have done that and it still doesn't work. How can I fix this?

Comment: Include the `<script>` inside the `<body>` at the end.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to close your  tags. Your code can't see 'div2' because 'div' is never getting closed.

```
<div id='div'></div>
<div id='div2'></div>
```

Then, in your `again` function you're calling `document.write` which shouldn't be used after page load because it writes over anything you already had on the page. It is effectively removing your `<div>` tags, which is then causing an error when you're trying to access them. Plus, you're already putting that value on the page through `innerHTML`. Short story: remove the `document.write` line in the `button` function

Comment: Nope, just a normal coder who is getting better at troubleshooting

Comment: I'm sorry I edited the code and your solution doesn't work...

Comment: I tried that code and I didn't get any errors. What error are you getting now?

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null

Comment: On what line? I am not getting that error. Maybe you need to clear your cache? I copied and tested your code directly and it was fine.

Comment: Huh that's weird, line 26 or 27

Comment: I'm getting error when pressing ```again```

Comment: @red_panda - I updated my answer for that

Comment: I don't have  ```document.write``` in ```again```....

Comment: My mistake, in `button` function

Answer (score 0):

Change `<div id = 'div'>` to `<div id="div"></div>`

And change `<div id = 'div2'>` to `<div id="div2"></div>`

Comment: how is this relevant ?

Comment: But why? that doesn't make any sense?

Answer (score 0):

I just checked your code, it's working fine.
Try closing div tags

Comment: Yes I did that but it doesn't work still the same error

Comment: try this
document.querySelector('#div').innerHTML = html;